# How to square off my plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a plot of a list of values in Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import control
import numpy

array = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]

plt.plot(array)

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('ALE')

plt.show()
```

Currently, I get this plot:
[image]

How can I make the transitions square-wave edges (i.e. vertical lines) instead of inclined lines?

Comment: The problem is that you are only specifying the y-axis. The x-axis is just being enumerated starting from zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using `plt.step()` to make lines vertical

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ys = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
xs = range(array.size)

plt.step(xs, ys)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I expected. I didn't know about step method before. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You may use a step drawstyle, e.g.

```
plt.plot(array, drawstyle="steps-mid")
```

[image]

Depending on how time steps are defined here, you may also use 
`"steps-pre"` or `"steps-post"` and if your timesteps are not equidistant you still need to supply some x values to the plot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply the X values, rather than letting them default to consecutive integers.  hard-coding this would give us:

```
Xvals = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...]
```

Can you take it from there?  You have documentation and examples that show you how to make a 2D plot -- if not in your class materials, online with a simple search.

ADDITIONAL HINT:

You can make Xvals simply enough: increment the value if the current and previous elements are equal; otherwise, leave it alone

Comment: You're right. It makes sense now. Well, I'll try to create array for X values in some loop. Thanks!